# Extract Authorization from Response Header with JMeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, expression, token

I am new to JMeter. My app is getting authentication token from the server. I see it at Response Header:
[View Results Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkfYk.png)

I am trying to extract the authentication token with regular expression extractor:
[Regular Expression extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIoNK.png)

But it doesn't work. At the next call I get the default value instead of extracted authentication token. Thanks in advance on any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is a little bit vague.

1. You don't need quotation marks around `Authorization` and the regex itself
2. You need to change your regular expression to `(.*)`

Full Regular Expression:

```
Authorization: (.*)
```

References:

- [Regular Expressions User Manual Chapter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex)
- [USING REGULAR EXPRESSION EXTRACTOR](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl5 Regular Expression Syntax](http://mythryl.org/my-Perl5_Regular_Expression_Syntax.html)

Comment: I believe, RegEx should be "Authorization: (.*?)". So that it will not be greedy.

Comment: I believe you should test what you suggest prior to writing anything